OpenId Login with Firebase Authentication on mobile(iPhone) error
I added Firebase Authentication on my Angular webapp, then I integrated Line Login into firebase authentication using OpenId Connect, it works great on PC browser, but when I login with Safari on my iPhone, I got the following error:

Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may
happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally
cleared. Some specific scenarios are - 1) Using IDP-Initiated SAML
SSO. 2) Using signInWithRedirect in a storage-partitioned browser
environment.

But there is no problem with Google/Phone authentication.
I've been searching for possible reasons and solutions, the closest solution is:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices
I tried options 1, 2, and 3, but none of them worked(still works on PC though). Additionally, I am not using signInWithRedirect but signInWithPopup.
Is this sort of a bug in Firebase or Line?
Currently I've used signInWithCustomToken but it makes the login process a bit of ugly, and almost incapable to integrate other platform's authentication.
